# How can I connect PHP server [android]

Tags: php, android, android-networking

We are working on a social network app with my friends. I am the android developer of the project but I dont know android networking. We have a php server and I have to connect it but I dont know how can I do that. Can anyone give me a need example on how to make GET requests and etc.? I would be really grateful if anyone do. Thanks.

Btw I have searched stackoverflow and I found 2-3 answer but they didnt really help. I found sample codes on other sites but they are only code and there is not any good tutorial. What I need is just a simple example which sends a variable to php server and get a response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `import org.apache.http.*`

Tutorial: [How to connect Android with PHP, MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)